# How can I auto-switch the audio input to match the audio output device?

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone, webcam

On a desktop Mac without a webcam/mic (Pro, Studio, Mini, etc), is there a way to have the audio input device auto-switch to match the chosen output?

I have a wireless USB headset (HyperX if that matters), which has a mic, and so have an input and output device for it. The headset connects via a USB dongle, so it's always connected and seen by the OS, unlike a bluetooth headset. I also have speakers connected, and a mic in my Logitech webcam.

I only use either the headset pair, or the non-headset pair of devices - ie. webcam mic + speakers, and headset mic + headset. I can manually switch outputs from the menu bar Sound menu, but switching inputs requires holding down option and is annoying to have to switch both.

I'd like to have the input switch automatically whenever the output changes so I don't need to remember to do it too, or remember to hold option.

I'm on macOS 12.6.

Comment: Do you have an external display _and_ is your headset plugged into the display? Or is your headset plugged into a doc/hub?

Comment: @BryanH, yes, external display, but the headset is connected to a dock, not the display.